# why console log of an object outputs a string?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

The following code selects the current node on which the cursor is on inside a contenteditable:

```
var selection;
    if (window.getSelection){
        selection = window.getSelection();
    }
else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
    selection = document.selection;
}
var anchor_node = selection.anchorNode; //current node on which cursor is positioned
console.log(anchor_node);
```

the console.log says "text" that is the content of the node; but anchor_node is an object in fact

```
$('.result').val(anchor_node);
```

outputs "[object object]"; it works using:

```
$('.result').val(anchor_node.data);
```

so why the log outputs simply the content string? How can I log the whole anchor_node object?

Comment: Not sure why nikhil has deleted [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36205849/1414562) but you should use `console.dir`. From DOC: `Specifically, console.log gives special treatment to DOM elements, whereas console.dir does not. This is often useful when trying to see the full representation of the DOM JS object.`

Comment: ok thanks for this

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned what browser/debugger you're using, but Chrome's dev tools will output the element by rendering its outer HTML, but it's *live clickable*; you can even right-click it and choose "Reveal in Elements panel" if you want.

Another option (since nikhil deleted his answer, not sure why, went to vote it up and it wasn't there anymore) is to use `console.dir`, which doesn't try to treat DOM elements specially.

Re `console.log`'s special treatment of DOM elements (in some dev tools):

For instance:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("a"));
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">This is the anchor</a>
```

Example of the log, with me hovering the cursor over it — note how it highlights the element on the page:

[image]

Right-click and I can choose Reveal in Elements Panel:

[image]

The result if I do:

[image]